# react-tap-event-plugin ghost click issue

Tags: cordova, reactjs, phonegap-build

I am using Material UI and the react-tap-event-plugin to try and get rid of the 300ms delay on mobile devices.

I tried to replace all my onClick functions with onTouchTap. Desktop this works fine but on a device i get the ghost click. Every touchTap event is followed by it's click.

I followed the advice to prevent the click from happening..

```
injectTapEventPlugin({
  shouldRejectClick: function (lastTouchEventTimestamp, clickEventTimestamp) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

This causes my desktop clicks to stop functioning, which is to be expected and i can fix that with some device detection in the shouldRejectClick function.

However, i am still getting the ghost clicks on my device.

Has anyone come across a similar issue and resolved it? I've read everything i can find, and tried the react-fastclick plugin (https://github.com/JakeSidSmith/react-fastclick) which didn't work with React at all.

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? -- Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.